# Why not able to use an int in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code throws a javascript syntax error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
var num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;
int total1 = num1 + num2;
console.log('total1 is '+total1);
```

Why is this error thrown ?
Can I not use ints in javascript ?

Comment: Javascript is loosely typed. You can simply use `var` for all variables.

Comment: Because `int` does not exist in JavaScript and having two consecutive identifiers (`int` and `num2`) is a syntax error.

Comment: Because that's not how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JavaScript is a **dynamically typed language**. That means you do not have
>   to specify the data type of a variable when you declare it, and data
>   types are converted automatically as needed during script execution.

-- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Also, there is no integer data type in JavaScript just Number.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no `int` like PHP does. Instead use `parseInt()`

```
var num1 = 1;
var num2 = 2;
total1 = parseInt(num1,10) + parseInt(num2,10);
console.log('total1 is '+total1);
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: PHP does have `int` for defining variables? In PHP it is used only for type casting. It is better to refer to C/C++.

Comment: @VisioN - obviously not, I was referring to PHP's int for type juggling.

Comment: Why are you `parseInt`ing something that's *not* a string?  I don't understand what your code is trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have explicitly typed variables.

Variable types are determined at "runtime". In javascript you define a variable by either:

1. (bad) declaring it e.g. `num2 = 2;`
2. (good) declaring it with the `var` keyword e.g. `var num2 = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) are used in JavaScript.  Thus, you'd declare all of the variables with a "var".

Answer (score 0):

1) The type used for numbers in JavaScript is "double". That is a 64 bit float value. 
2) There is no type called int in JavaScript.
3) Every variable is a "variant". It can store numbers, strings, booleans and objects.

For your question if you just assign integer literals like "1234" to a variable it will still contain the correct value, so just summing the variables will still give you the correct answer, as your example requires.